# $.get PHP file in JS when link clicked

Tags: php, javascript, sql, ajax

The link:

```
<a class='dropdown' href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='mainLoginToggle();'>
```

mainLoginToggle():

```
function mainLoginToggle() {    
    $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
        var container = $(".logindisplay");
        if (container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
            container.fadeOut(222);
        }
    });
if (document.getElementById('logindisplay').style.display == 'block') {
    $(".logindisplay").fadeOut(222);
} else {
    $(".logindisplay").fadeIn(222);
}
    $.get("../include/removenotif.php");
    return false;
}
```

removenotif.php:

```
<?php include("session.php"); $database->removeNotifications($session->username); ?>
```

removeNotification():

```
    function removeNotifications($user) {
        $q = "UPDATE notifications SET seen = '1' WHERE username = '$user'";
        $result = mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
        return true;
    }
```

Basically, when the link is clicked it shows and hides the div, but also when it's clicked it's supposed to run the removeNotifications function, and not return any messages but successfully run the sql query. But it's not executing the query.

I've tested to see if the page is actually being called by changing the header information to try and get an error but nothing is happening. I'm not really sure where I'm going wrong here, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try adding `echo mysql_error();` and see what the error is? Make sure `display_errors` in your PHP.ini is On, otherwise use  `ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: It's not actually running the query though.

Comment: What do you have in the browser console? Any Javascript errors? Also, verify that the path to the PHP file is correct.

Comment: Nope, the GET is fine, status 200. takes 1.18s though :/

Comment: Did you try the above suggestion? Do you see any error in the query? What do you mean by query is not running? The `removeNotifications` is getting executed, and the query is not running. That's not possible, it should be getting some kinda error which is not shown by default.

Comment: Also try loading removenotif.php directly in your browser to see what happens

Comment: @s_ha_dum do you mean use the full path to the page?

Comment: @Tom, not necessarily but that is the safe way to go. I just meant to make sure that the file is being loaded correctly. The easiest way to do that is with the FireFox extension HttpFox. You should see if the request 404s.

Comment: I can see in the console that the request is completed sucessfully. Returns status code 200. It takes ~1s to complete though.

Comment: Load the page directly in the browser as suggested by @Roy and start dumping values. You need to isolate where it breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use JQuery all the way?

Like this

Your link

```
<a class="dropdown" href="#">Click here</a>
```

Jquery

```
       $(document).ready(function() {

           $('.dropdown').live('click', function(){

               var container = $(".logindisplay");
               if (container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
                   container.fadeOut(222);
                   }

                if (document.getElementById('logindisplay').style.display == 'block') {
                    $(".logindisplay").fadeOut(222);
                } else {
                    $(".logindisplay").fadeIn(222);
                }
                    $.get("../include/removenotif.php");
                    return false;

           });

        });
```

This way the PHP file is called.

Wezy